# variable declared in member function is same as member variable

Tags: c++

wondering whether this gonna work, and how:

```
class sample
{
 int i;
 int func1()
  {
   int i = 0;
   i++;
   return i;
  }
}
```

reason I ask is because I have many member functions and bad name conventions.

Comment: scope matters. The variable `i` in the class scope is not the same as the one in the function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things get weird with scopes:

```
int func1()
{
    int i = 0;
    i++;
    { //1
        int i = 41;
        i++;
    }
    { //2
        int j = i + 1;
        cout << j << endl // this prints 2
    }
    return i;
}
```

The rule when using variables in scope is, it always refers to the most local scope first and works it way up. So in your example the `i` inside your function will not refer to the `i` in the class.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `int i = 0` you're creating a new variable called `i` that hides the class member. If you want to access the class's `i`, you can do `this->i`. But it's usually better not to cause that kind of confusion in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the body of `func1`, you will be referencing the locally declared `int i`. In order to reference the class member, you need to reference it explicitly by using the `this` pointer:

```
this->i
```

`this` is a const pointer passed in to all methods in a class to represent the current instance. It is not passed in when you have a `static` member function of course.

The reason the locally declared `int i` is being used first is because it is in the same scope as `i++` and `return i`.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. All uses of the name `i` inside the function refer to the `i` declared inside that function. That is, the function will return 1 every time.

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention of i inside the func1(). Do you want to increment the outside i or the i inside the function. If you want the outside i to increment then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The return will in fact refer to the `i` declared in `func1()`. It's all about scopes.

A scope starts with `{` and end with `}`. All variables declared inside a scope will only be defined as long you stay within the scope or if you go into another scope. Hence

```
{ int i = 0; { int i = 1; { int i = 2; }}}
```

is perfectly possible. If you use `i` in one of the scopes you will always refer to the `i` in the same scope. To refer to an `i` of a higher scope is more difficult.

In your example you can still refer to the top `i` by using `this->i`, where `this` is a pointer to the object you are working with. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) is some more info (scroll a bit down).